# Zend Studio code formatter problem with comments

Tags: zend-studio, comments, indentation, formatter

i have Zend Studio 7.x, mostly use it for Zend Framework PHP and OOP JavaScript.
When i run formatter on *.php file, often space is added after block of inline comments

Before formatter run:

```
<?php
function someAction() {

 // some note
 // second line
 if ($foo) {
 }

}
?>
```

After:

```
<?php
function someAction() {

 // some note
 // second line

 if ($foo) {
 }

}
?>
```

If i run formatter one more time next empty line after // is added,
Code is formatted in right way but blank lines are frustrating.
Something similar happens in *.js files.

Any idea?